# What's a good tool for making a threatening AI robot voice?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, speech-synthesis

I'm looking for a text to speech tool to generate an AI voice for my game. There are a lot of options out there that generate almost human sounding voices and impressions of celebrities, but I'm looking for a voice that:

- Is obviously robotic
- Sounds threatening/evil
- Sounds somewhat
  lifelike.
- Has a license that will let me use the voice for my video game and in any marketing material

Think like a male version of the G.L.A.D.O.S voice or a more threatening version of Machine Head from invincible.

Comment: Thanks for the upvotes, now let's see some answers lol